# Is $\emptyset$ a subset of $A-\emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently was given an assignment to help out a student with a class I've never taken. I've dealt with set theory before and I'm aware $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set, but this question is stumping me and I can't seem to find any answers.

The original question is this: Is it always true that $A-B$ is a subset of $A-\emptyset$? What I'm working with now is if $A \subseteq B$, then $A-B = \emptyset$. Now, $\emptyset \subseteq A$, and given that $\emptyset-\emptyset= \emptyset$, I'm inclined to believe that the conjecture is in fact true.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: $A\setminus B$ is by definition the set of things that are in $A$ but not in $B$, so it is by definition a subset of $A$. And $A\setminus\varnothing=A$, since no element of $A$ belongs to $\varnothing$, so $A\setminus B\subseteq A\setminus\varnothing$.

Comment: $\varnothing$ is **ALWAYS** a subset of any set.  Indeed, $\varnothing\subset \varnothing$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, that answers my question.

Comment: @Lo12: You’re welcome.

Comment: Perhaps Lo12 you could write up the solution in your own words, and post it as an answer.